# How can I filter out objects where todays date falls within a range of a calculated date?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

Here is the code I currently have.

```
    models = Model.objects.annotate(
        start_range=ExpressionWrapper(
            F('a_date_on_the_model') + datetime.timedelta(days=-7),
            output_field=DateField(),
        ),
        end_range=ExpressionWrapper(
            F('a_date_on_the_model') + datetime.timedelta(days=-2),
            output_field=DateField(),
        )
    ).filter(
        F('today')__range=[F('start_range'), F('end_range')]
    )
```

Obviously I can not do a range on `F('today')` because it's not a database column / keyword but I'm just showing that I have a variable called today that I'm trying to compare against.  I feel like I'm close but could use some help wrapping this up. Note: `-7` and `-2` will be dynamic days but just hardcoded for example. These number and days can be positive or negative but the first number will always be greater than the second number of course.

Edit - This is what the PSQL would look like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN (a_date_on_the_model + INTERVAL '-7 day') AND (a_date_on_the_model + INTERVAL '-1 day');
```

Comment: Can you show your model? I'm confused about what fields you actually have.

Comment: Oh sorry, `a_date_on_the_model ` is a field on the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can annotate today.

```
today=Value(datetime.datetime.now().date(), output_field=DateField())
```

and then I can do:

```
today__range=[F('start_range'), F('end_range')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, but I don't think you need to use annotate for this. I'm not sure if the operators I'm using for the datetimes match what you want exactly, but if you tweak this I think you'll get a queryset that you want.

```py
# Get models where the date is less than 7 days old, but more than 2
# days old.
models = Model.objects.exclude(
    a_date_on_the_model__range=(
        today - timedelta(days=7),
        today - timedelta(days=2),
    )
)
```

Comment: One curveball I maybe didn’t mention is that days can be positive or negative.  That means that it can be a range that starts with a date before “a_date_on_the_model” and ends with a date after “a_date_on_the_model“